# Add checkboxes to a list of dynamically generated result

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a list of result listed after extracting from a .txt file. I would like to add a checkbox behind every results listed. The following is my code:

```
    private void LoadFile() {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt");
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
            sr.Close();

            for (int i = 3; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                resultsTreeView.Items.Add(lines[i].ToString().Substring(67,17));
                resultsTreeView.Items.Add(CheckBox[i]);
            }
```

How can I add checkboxes as the results extracted will change every time? I would like to track which boxes has checked as well so that I can print the result to users. Thank you!

Comment: If you please make your question more clear and provide the criteria upon which you determine if a check box has to be checked or not :)

Comment: Hi @SirajMansour, the check box do not need to be checked. It is up to user selection and user will tick the check boxes where he feels necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            for (int i = 3; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                resultsTreeView.Items.Add(lines[i].ToString().Substring(67,17));
                resultsTreeView.Items.Add(new CheckBox()); 
                // resultsTreeView.Items.Add(BuildCheckBox())
            }
```

OR

```
CheckBox BuildCheckbox()
{
   CheckBox C = new CheckBox();
   return C;
}
```

That's all you need to create a checkbox, or you can create a function that returns a checkbox, inside it you create a new instance of checkbox and set the attributes/subscribe to events the way you want and return it.

As for the tracking which checkboxes are checked, I only need you to provide me with the type of your "resultsTreeView"

EDIT :

To loop through checkboxes in the TreeView and do something on the checked ones:

```
resultsTreeView.Items.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList()
                .ForEach(C => 
                { 
                    if (C.IsChecked.HasValue && C.IsChecked.Value == true) 
                    { 
                        //DoSomething
                    } 
                });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The type of resultsTreeView do you mean string? If so can you guide me through? Thanks!

Comment: Am sorry my fault, i should've noticed you're using WPF.

Comment: Please check my edit, i added for you the way to loop through the checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for your help. I able to add check boxes. However, it seems that I can't print the list of checked result to user.

Comment: Tell me exactly what do you want to print ? The loop i added up there loops through checkbox items in your treeview, you can do whatever you want there. give me an example using your treeview of something you want to print and i will try to help :)

Comment: The list of result (checkbox items) are in "Date" "Time" format. For instance, 8/7/2013 21:26:30, 6/7/2013 13:30:12 and so on. User should be able to select the row of date and time that they want by assigning a tick on the checkboxes (we have done till this part). Next, I would like to display the date and time that user has selected. For instance, a new window will pop out and say that "The selected date and time is: 4/6/2013 4:23:45, 1/3/2013 4:56:40 and so on. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for.  I assume resultsTreeView is a TreeViewItem.  and I also assume that you are working in wpf.  You can do the following through wpf.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
{
    resultsTreeView.Items.Add(lines[i].ToString().Substring(67,17));
}


<TreeView x:Name="resultsTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="37,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <CheckBox/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Something similar could be done through code behind

```
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count(); i++)
{
    resultsTreeView.Items.Add(mylist[i]);
}
resultsTreeView.ItemTemplate = TreeViewDataTemp;
```

And then create TreeViewDataTemp the following way

```
private static DataTemplate TreeViewDataTemp
    {
        get
        {
            DataTemplate TVDT = new DataTemplate();

            FrameworkElementFactory Stack = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
            Stack.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

            FrameworkElementFactory TextB = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            TextB.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding());

            FrameworkElementFactory ChkBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));

            Stack.AppendChild(TextB);
            Stack.AppendChild(ChkBox);

            TVDT.VisualTree = Stack;

            return TVDT;
        }
    }
```

The above gives you 1 item which is text together with a checkbox.
Alternatively your method will add a checkbox as a new item after every string item that you add.. which is

```
for (int I=0; I<lines.Count(); I++)
{
    resultsTreeView.Items.Add(mylist[i]);
    resultsTreeView.Items.Add(new CheckBox());
}
```